# Stripe charge a connected account by platform account

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to charge a connected account by platform account. (I have a secret key of my account and created a connected account, so there is an account_id). By which method I can achieve this? I really got confused by Stripe's documentation. Thanks

Comment: Stripe Connect is designed to allow you to created charges for connected accounts, rather than charge them directly. To charge someone's bank account, you instead follow https://stripe.com/docs/ach (not using Connect).

Comment: I don't want to charge their bank account. I want to charge their stripe account.

Comment: You don't charge a Stripe Account directly. You charge a PaymentMethod (card, bank account, etc.). Accounts (via Connect) are other merchants, which are different from Customers that have PaymentMethods.

Comment: So, you mean I can't charge a PaymentMethod through Stripe connect?

Comment: You can charge a PaymentMethod from a connected Account. See https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges

Comment: @taintedzodiac in this link stripe docs mentions: `When accepting a payment from a customer, you need to create a charge.` I am not accepting payment. The user uses a gift and gets a discount in the shopping center. Then I should pay for the shopping center on behalf of the user. How is this possible with stripe connect?

Comment: Stripe Connect is used to make API calls on behalf of connected Stripe accounts. Could you elaborate on where funds are moving to/from when you mention using a gift and getting a discount?